# Code behaves differently on google chrome than on safari

Tags: javascript, html

I am coding a videogame that involves the person to travel through the solar system to accomplish objectives. The code behaves how I want it to when I open the website in safari but when I play the game on chrome and press my mouse button, the planets (divs and images that were placed in specific coordinates) teleport to the earth div or somewhere near it. I have done enough research to find out that this is because chrome handles event listeners differently but I don't know how to fix it.

this is the full script.js file:

```
var screen = document.getElementById("screen")
var objects = []
var locaters = [];
function afterStory() {
  var kmAwayFromSun = 149600000;
  //https://docs.google.com/document/d/1fgZcHTpHdXvOq_DIz2
  //a5pknkoFt0F6oQqmNTV5QXZ4g/edit
  //sun: 2992000 px away
  var moveInterval = [];
  var kmText = document.getElementById("kmFromSun");
  var speedLevel = document.getElementById("speeed");
  var spaceship = document.getElementById("spaceship")
  var mercury = document.getElementById("mercury");
  mercury.style.left = "-1831700px";
  mercury.style.top = "190px";
  var venus = document.getElementById("venus");
  venus.style.left = "-851700px";
  venus.style.top = "60px";
  var earth = document.getElementById("earth");
  earth.style.left = "172.5px";
  earth.style.top = "72.5px";
  var mars = document.getElementById("mars");
  mars.style.left = "2768300px";
  mars.style.top = "72.5px";
  var jupiter = document.getElementById("jupiter");
  jupiter.style.left = "12568000.8px";
  jupiter.style.top = "60px";
  var saturn = document.getElementById("saturn");
  saturn.style.left = "25008000px";
  saturn.style.top = "1198.2px";
  objects.push(mercury);
  objects.push(venus);
  objects.push(earth);
  objects.push(mars);
  objects.push(jupiter);
  objects.push(saturn);
  //1px = 50 km
  //mercury width = 20px or 9758 km
  //mercury -1832000 px
  var lmercury = document.getElementById("lmercury");
  var lvenus = document.getElementById("lvenus");
  var learth = document.getElementById("learth");
  var lmars = document.getElementById("lmars");
  var ljupiter = document.getElementById("ljupiter");
  var lsaturn = document.getElementById("lsaturn");
  locaters.push(lmercury);
  locaters.push(lvenus);
  locaters.push(learth);
  locaters.push(lmars);
  locaters.push(ljupiter);
  locaters.push(lsaturn);
  lmercury.src = "assets/Locaters/Mercury.png";
  var locatingPlanet = mercury;
  var planetName = "mercury";
  var limit = 30;
  var mousePosition;
  var velocity = [0, 0];
  var isDown = false;
  var speed = 10;
  
    
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    isDown = true;
  }, true);
  
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
    isDown = false;
    velocity = [0, 0];
  }, true);
  
  document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    for (var a = 0; a < objects.length; a++) {
      var object = objects[a]
      var locater = locaters[a];
      var objectX = parseInt(object.style.left);
      var objectY = parseInt(object.style.top);
      var mouseX = e.clientX;
      var mouseY = e.clientY;
      var deltaX = mouseX - objectX;
      var deltaY = mouseY - objectY;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
      var velocityX = deltaX / distance * speed;
      var velocityY = deltaY / distance * speed;
      velocity[0] = velocityX;
      velocity[1] = velocityY;
      var x = e.clientX - 300;
      var y = e.clientY - 200;
      var angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;
      spaceship.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    
      // Start moving the object towards the mouse pointer
      moveInterval[a] = setInterval((function(obj, loc) {
        return function() {
          var objectX = 300;
          var objectY = 200;
          var mouseX = e.clientX;
          var mouseY = e.clientY;
          var deltaX = mousePosition.x - objectX;
          var deltaY = mousePosition.y - objectY;
          var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
          var objectX = parseInt(obj.style.left);
          var objectY = parseInt(obj.style.top);
          obj.style.left = (objectX - velocity[0]) + 'px';
          obj.style.top  = (objectY - velocity[1]) + 'px';
          kmAwayFromSun += velocity[0]*50/objects.length;
          var x = 300 - obj.offsetLeft;
          var y = 200 - obj.offsetTop;
          var angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
          loc.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
          kmText.innerText = `km From Sun: ${Math.round(kmAwayFromSun)}`
              
          //console.log(speed)
          velocity[0] = deltaX / distance * speed;
          velocity[1] = deltaY / distance * speed;
          
          // calculate the angle between the locater and the planet
          var planetX = parseInt(object.style.left) + (object.offsetWidth / 2);
          var planetY = parseInt(object.style.top) + (object.offsetHeight / 2);
          var locaterX = parseInt(loc.style.left) + (loc.offsetWidth / 2);
          var locaterY = parseInt(loc.style.top) + (loc.offsetHeight / 2);
          var deltaX = planetX - locaterX;
          var deltaY = planetY - locaterY;
          var angle = (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
          loc.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
        }
      })(object, locater), 50);
      // Stop moving the object when the mouse button is released
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        for (var i=0; i<moveInterval.length;i++) {
          clearInterval(moveInterval[i]);
        }
      }, true);
    }
    
  }, true);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (event) => {
    const keyPressed = event.key;
    console.log(keyPressed)
    if (keyPressed == "e") {
      if (speed == 100000) {
        speed = 10;
        speedLevel.innerText = "Speed Level: 1x";
      }
      else if (speed == 10) {
        speed = 100;
        speedLevel.innerText = "Speed Level: 10x";
      }
      else if (speed == 100) {
        speed = 1000;
        speedLevel.innerText = "Speed Level: 100x";
      }
      else if (speed == 1000) {
        speed = 10000;
        speedLevel.innerText = "Speed Level: 1000x";
      }
      else if (speed == 10000) {
        speed = 100000;
        speedLevel.innerText = "Speed Level: 10000x";
      }
    }
  }, false)
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
    mousePosition = {
      x : e.clientX,
      y : e.clientY
    };
    if (isDown) {
      var objectX = 300;
      var objectY = 200;
      var mouseX = e.clientX;
      var mouseY = e.clientY;
      var deltaX = mousePosition.x - objectX;
      var deltaY = mousePosition.y - objectY;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
      var maxVelocity = 20*speed; // set maximum velocity here
      //console.log(speed)
      velocity[0] = deltaX / distance * speed;
      velocity[1] = deltaY / distance * speed;
      if (distance > maxVelocity) { // limit velocity to maxVelocity
        velocity[0] = velocity[0] / distance * maxVelocity;
        velocity[1] = velocity[1] / distance * maxVelocity;
      }
      //rotate the spaceship
      var x = e.clientX - spaceship.offsetLeft;
      var y = e.clientY - spaceship.offsetTop;
      var angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;
      spaceship.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    }
  }, true);
  document.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
    const keyPressed = e.key;
    if (keyPressed == "l") {
      var lpx = parseInt(locatingPlanet.style.left);
      var lpy = parseInt(locatingPlanet.style.top);
      if (lpx<=300+limit && lpx>=300-limit && lpy>=200-limit && lpy<=200+limit) {
        enterPlanet(planetName)
      }
    }
  }, false)
  
  
}

function enterPlanet(pName) {
  if (pName == "mercury") {
    var newScreen = screen.cloneNode(true);
    

    
  }
}
function startStory() {
  
}
afterStory();
```

this is the event listener that I think is the issue:

```
document.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
    for (var a = 0; a < objects.length; a++) {
      var object = objects[a]
      var locater = locaters[a];
      var objectX = parseInt(object.style.left);
      var objectY = parseInt(object.style.top);
      var mouseX = e.clientX;
      var mouseY = e.clientY;
      var deltaX = mouseX - objectX;
      var deltaY = mouseY - objectY;
      var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
      var velocityX = deltaX / distance * speed;
      var velocityY = deltaY / distance * speed;
      velocity[0] = velocityX;
      velocity[1] = velocityY;
      var x = e.clientX - 300;
      var y = e.clientY - 200;
      var angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) + 90;
      spaceship.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
    
      // Start moving the object towards the mouse pointer
      moveInterval[a] = setInterval((function(obj, loc) {
        return function() {
          var objectX = 300;
          var objectY = 200;
          var mouseX = e.clientX;
          var mouseY = e.clientY;
          var deltaX = mousePosition.x - objectX;
          var deltaY = mousePosition.y - objectY;
          var distance = Math.sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
          var objectX = parseInt(obj.style.left);
          var objectY = parseInt(obj.style.top);
          obj.style.left = (objectX - velocity[0]) + 'px';
          obj.style.top  = (objectY - velocity[1]) + 'px';
          kmAwayFromSun += velocity[0]*50/objects.length;
          var x = 300 - obj.offsetLeft;
          var y = 200 - obj.offsetTop;
          var angle = (Math.atan2(y, x) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
          loc.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
          kmText.innerText = `km From Sun: ${Math.round(kmAwayFromSun)}`
              
          //console.log(speed)
          velocity[0] = deltaX / distance * speed;
          velocity[1] = deltaY / distance * speed;
          
          // calculate the angle between the locater and the planet
          var planetX = parseInt(object.style.left) + (object.offsetWidth / 2);
          var planetY = parseInt(object.style.top) + (object.offsetHeight / 2);
          var locaterX = parseInt(loc.style.left) + (loc.offsetWidth / 2);
          var locaterY = parseInt(loc.style.top) + (loc.offsetHeight / 2);
          var deltaX = planetX - locaterX;
          var deltaY = planetY - locaterY;
          var angle = (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI) - 90;
          loc.style.transform = "rotate(" + angle + "deg)";
        }
      })(object, locater), 50);
      // Stop moving the object when the mouse button is released
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
        for (var i=0; i<moveInterval.length;i++) {
          clearInterval(moveInterval[i]);
        }
      }, true);
    }
    
  }, true);
```

this is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>replit</title>
  <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  
</head>

<body>
  <div id="screen" class = "unselectable">
    <div id = "mercury"></div>
    <div id = "venus"></div>
    <div id = "earth"></div>
    <div id = "mars"></div>
    <img src = "assets/jupiter.png" id = "jupiter" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src = "assets/saturn.png" id = "saturn" draggable = "false"></img>
    <div id = "uranus"></div>
    <div id = "neptune"></div>
    <img src = "assets/spaceship.png" id = "spaceship" draggable = "false"></img>
    <div id = "kmFromSun">km from sun: 149600000 km</div>
    <div id = "speeed">Speed Level: 1x</div>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="learth" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="lmercury" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="lvenus" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="lmars" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="ljupiter" draggable = "false"></img>
    <img src="assets/Locaters/Invis.png" class="locaters" id="lsaturn" draggable = "false"></img>
  </div>
  <!--<img style="width:600px;height:400px;position:absolute;top:0px;left:0px" src="https://imageio.forbes.com/specials-images/imageserve/5ed68e8310716f0007411996/0x0.jpg?format=jpg&width=1200" draggable="false"></img> -->
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

the 'Locater' file just contains arrows of different color that rotate to point at their planets.

I tried to console.log() the velocity array to see if the first one is different than the rest, but the velocity remains the same as I keep pressing my mouse button on the same point, somehow, the coordinates are changing by themselves, and also, the style.top value doesn't change when the divs teleport only the style.left. I have found out the change occurs either in the setInterval or after it but it only happens once, pressing the mouse button after makes the code behave normal again.

Comment: That's a lot of `var`s... At the very least, swap those out for `let` and `const`, especially if you're already using `const` in other parts of your code.

Comment: Consider doing some debugging to narrow-down where in this code the issue lies

Comment: `console.log()` is one way to help trace the flow of control and the changes to variables over time.  It can help narrow down the code to look at more closely.

Comment: that's a good idea, imma do that

Comment: Please edit your question to include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the shortest code necessary to replicate the issue.